# noindex on pop-up comments

Tags: wordpress, seo, popup, http-status-code-404, noindex

I'm using pop-up comments on my wordpress blog. I know that most people don't recommend this but my audience really likes the comments this way.

But recently I discovered that Google is indexing the temporary pop-up comments pages generating a lot of 404 errors.

How do I make Google ignore the pop up pages? Can I add noindex, nofollow and noarchive on these pages? They are automatically generated when a person clicks on the Comments link.

My page: `http://www.sedentario.org/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the comments-popup.php file in your WordPress theme and add:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
```

Beyond that I would be looking at why 404 errors are being generated since every post should have a comments link.